# Martingale convergence theorem for Poisson.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $\{A_n\}_n$ be random variables such that $A_0=1$ and given $\{A_j, j=0,\dots , n-1\}, A_n \sim Poisson(A_{n-1}).$
It is straightforward that $\mathbb{E}[A_n| A_1, \dots , A_{n-1}]=A_{n-1}$, and that $\{A_j\}$ is a nonnegative martingale. By martingale convergence theorem, we get $\lim{A_n}=a < \infty.$ Is there anything I can say for $P(A_n =k| A_j)=\frac{A_{n-1}^k}{k!}e^{-A_{n-1}}$? I'm kind of lost, any hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the generating function of $a$. Evidently
$$
\Bbb E[s^{A_n}]=\Bbb E[e^{-A_{n-1}(1-s)}], 
$$
so letting $n\to\infty$ we obtain
$$
\Bbb E[s^a]=\Bbb E[e^{-a(1-s)}].
$$
Now let $s\to 0+$:
$$
\Bbb P[a=0] = \Bbb E[e^{-a}]=\Bbb P[a=0]+\Bbb E [e^{-a}1_{\{a\ge 1\}}].
$$
Thus $\Bbb E[e^{-a}1_{\{a\ge 1\}}]=0$, forcing $\Bbb P[a=0]=1$.

Comment: Could you tell me how far from correct is the solution I proposed above? Thanks a lot for the idea btw, had completely mislooked that line of thought.

Comment: could you explain how $s\to 0+$ leads to $  E[s^a] =  \Bbb P[a=0]$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it, but i'm not sure about a certain part of my proof.
Anyways, since $A_n$ given the previous $A_j$ is $Poisson(A_{n-1}) \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}\{A_n^2 | A_1, \dots, A_{n-1}\} = A_{n-1}^2 + A_{n-1} (*)$

 now taking limits as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in $(*)$ we get that $a^2=a^2+a \Rightarrow a=0$. 
My question is the following: is it legit to take such limit in the conditional expectation with respect to such a $\sigma$-algebra?
Intuitively, I think it should be OK, since as $n$ increases to $N$ (large), the conditional expectation of our interest is calculated given $A_1, \dots A_{N-1},$ thing that is required in order for $A_N$ to keep it's Poisson distribution (since A_N is Poisson onlygiven the previous values of $A_j$).

Comment: Your taking of limits here is questionable. For example, if $\sup_n A^2_n$
were integrable, then $\Bbb E[A^2_n|A_1,\ldots,A_{n−1}]$ would converge a.e. (and in $L^1$) to $\Bbb E[a^2|A_1,A_2,\ldots]=a^2$, and you would have $a^2=a^2+a$ a.s.,  as desired, hence $a=0$, a.s. But the integrability of $\sup_nA^2_n$ would also imply that $\{A_n\}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, hence $\Bbb E[a]=\lim_n\Bbb E[A_n]=1$. This contradiction means that  $\sup_nA^2_n$ cannot be integrable.

Comment: Yeah I see, so what I did would be OK only if I could make dominated convergence (or an alternative) hold. Thanks.